# Do Angular use webpack and where is a webpack configuration file?

Tags: angular

In Angular(Angular version 7)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

I saw code `import` is it means that Angular use webpack and where is the webpack configuration file ?

Do I need to know webpack for succeed angular ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I saw code import is it means that Angular use webpack

No. It means it uses standard TypeScript / EcmaScript imports. The Angular **CLI** does use Webpack, though.

> where is the webpack configuration file

There is none. The Webpack configuration(s) is (are) hidden for you by the Angular CLI.

> Do I need to know webpack for succeed angular ?

No.